# Function converting a float, base to float

Tags: python, function, radix

Trying to create function to calculate a float, from a float and base. How do we go about that?

Here is what I have done

```
def frac(s, base):
    import math
    exp = range(math.log(s, base), -1, -1)
    for e in exp:
        d = (s // (base ** e))
        s -= d * (base ** e)
        yield d
```

try to target something like

```
(100.101, base=2) = 4.625
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is easiest to use the built-in integer functionality on the string without the decimal point, then divide by the base raised to the number of decimal places.

```
def frac (s, base):
    dotPos=s.find('.')
    if (dotPos == -1):
        return (int(s, base))
    places = len(s)-dotPos-1
    return (1.0*int(s[:dotPos]+s[dotPos+1:],base)/(base**places))
print frac("100.1",2)
```